# How do I call a previously constucted class in a new constructor?

Tags: java

Creating a program for my CS class and basically a program (created by my instructor) created a program that makes book titles and authors, the code will then run through my program which will construct a Book Class and and Author Class to make sure that they are operational my problem is that on line 12 of my instructor's code "a3" which is an author is called in my book Class and I don't know how to call my first class in my second class constructor.
As is I get an error that says "expecting triple dot."

```
//my code

public class Author {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  //variables
  public Author (String a) {
    firstName = a;
  }
  public Author (String a, String b) {
    firstName = a;
    lastName = b;
  }
}


public class Book {
  String Title;
  String a;
  //variables
  public Book (String c, Author) {
    Title = c;
  }
  public Book () {
  }
}





// instructor's code

  void setup() { 
  Book [] allTheBooks = new Book[30]; 
  int score = 6; 
  int tScore = 0;

  System.out.println( "Attempting constructors:" );

  Author a1 = new Author( "Ballard", "J.G." );
  Author a2 = new Author( "Eggers", "Dave" );
  Author a3 = new Author( "Catton", "Eleanor" );
  Author a4 = new Author( "Adler", "Renata" );


  System.out.println( "  - Author constructors seem functional:  3/3" );



  allTheBooks[1] = new Book( "The Circle" );
  allTheBooks[2] = new Book( "The Luminaries", a3 );
  allTheBooks[3] = new Book();
  allTheBooks[4] = new Book( "Pitch Dark" );
  allTheBooks[5] = new Book( "Speedboat" );
  allTheBooks[6] = new Book();
  allTheBooks[7] = new Book( "The Dissident Gardens" );

  System.out.println( "  - Book constructors seem functional:    3/3" );
}
```

Comment: `public Book (String c, Author)`: you have to provide a name for the `Author` parameter, just like you did for all the `String` parameters to other constructors.

Comment: Never mind the last comment, you actually don't have an `Author` in your `Book`. What will you do with the passed `Author` once you get that working?